# inconsistent results with boost::locale collation

Tags: c++, internationalization

When comparing the following UTF-8 string pairs using boost::locale (any backend) at the "identical" level (accents are relevant) and a UTF-8 locale (I tried de_DE.utf-8) on Debian Testing (boost 1.49), I get a result that does not make sense to me.

"Muller" is considered less than "Müller" (as expected), but "Muller 2" is considered more than "Müller 1", despite the different result for the names alone.

Do I have bug in my code, in the underlying libraries or in my expectations?

```
#include <locale.h>

#include <boost/locale.hpp>
#include <boost/assign/std/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <boost/assign/list_of.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/join.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

    std::cout << "backends: " <<
        boost::join(boost::locale::localization_backend_manager::global().get_all_backends(),
                    ", ") << std::endl;
    boost::locale::localization_backend_manager::global().select(argc > 2 ? argv[2] : "icu");
    std::locale loc = boost::locale::generator()(argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "de_DE.UTF-8");

    typedef boost::tuple<std::string, std::string> string_pair_t;
    std::vector<string_pair_t> pairs =
        boost::assign::tuple_list_of("Muller", "Müller")
        ("Muller 2", "Müller 1")
        ("Muller B", "Müller A");
    BOOST_FOREACH (const string_pair_t &pair, pairs) {
        const std::string &a = boost::get<0>(pair),
            &b = boost::get<1>(pair);
        int cmp = std::use_facet<boost::locale::collator<char> >(loc).
            compare(boost::locale::collator_base::identical, a, b);
        std::cout <<
            a << " and " << b <<
            " are " <<
            (cmp == 0 ? "identical" : "different") <<
            " (" <<
            (cmp < 0 ? '<' :
                   cmp > 0 ? '>' : '=') <<
            ")" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output on my system:

```
$ /tmp/mueller de_DE.utf-8 icu
backends: icu, posix, std
Muller and Müller are different (<)
Muller 2 and Müller 1 are different (>)
Muller B and Müller A are different (>)
```

Answer (score 0):

The unexpected result came from not understanding how the Unicode collation algorithm works: it will always start with the lowest level and use that result if strings are considered different already at that level. Allowing higher levels will only lead to different results where lower levels did not find a relevant difference between strings.